# another domain pointing to an area of a site

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, dns, web

how would i go about implementing something like the following...

example.com site has these pages:

```
example.com/id1/page1/
example.com/id1/page2/
example.com/id1/page3/
example.com/id2/page1/
example.com/id2/page2/
example.com/id2/page3/
```

and now i want to have that when i point domains `example1.com` and `example2.com` to `example.com/id1/` page and `example.com/id2/page1/` respectively.

the site is on azure and what i did was set a dns for all three domains (`example.com`, `example1.com`, `example2.com`) to point to the same ip.

and then on the home page of the site i do a redirect with
    Response.Redirect(...);

but this means that the domains `example1.com` and `example2.com` are not seen in the browser url, but rather the urls such as `example.com/id1/` and `example.com/id2/` are seen instead.

what i would instead like is to have my site show as the actual domain in such a way that these URL's are never seen:

```
example.com/id1/
example.com/id1/page1/
example.com/id1/page2/
example.com/id1/page3/
example.com/id2/
example.com/id2/page1/
example.com/id2/page2/
example.com/id2/page3/
```

and instead they respectively show up as as

```
example1.com/
example1.com/profile/
example1.com/about/
example1.com/contact/
example2.com/
example2.com/profile/
example2.com/about/
example2.com/contact/
```

so what do i need to change to make the domains visible as such?
sorry for the long question :( hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do that using a redirect since, as you mentioned, you want to keep the URL displayed as the one typed in. What you are trying to do is URL routing. For ASP.NET, the process and configuration is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

If your list of pages is limited, you can do routing statically. Or you can provide the route table based on a database of pages or something. The walkthrough here explains how to provide those routes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: oh. i've used routes before, just didn't think they can be used accross domains... are you talking about the code (on the links above): routes.MapPageRoute("","SalesReportSummary/{year}","~/sales.aspx");
and i could for example change it to be routes.MapPageRoute("","SalesReportSummary/{year}","http: //example1.com"); and that would work?